# Creating manipulable diagrams in python

Tags: python, diagram

I want to create a piece of software that allows me to create manipulable diagrams (state machine alike) in python. What library should I use (does at least one exist)?

I found this js library (https://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html), but I'd like to create the whole program in python.
I did not found something that lets you work with diagrams from the UI standpoint.

I would like to be able to click on a certain diagram and edit its contents and manipulate the contests of all diagram objects.

Comment: Do you want a library with GUI or just a library?

Comment: @LazyCoder, I want something that allows me to do something like GoJs. To create and manipulate diagrams. Anything is good for me.

Comment: by software, you mean desktop app or a website can work for you?

Comment: @IanauAndrei wants to **create** a piece of software, right? You've got tools buddy.

Comment: This question is OT here.

Answer (score 0):

Use pysimpleautomata library [pysimpleautomata](https://pysimpleautomata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
You might have to create your own api to create interface though. For that, I'd suggest using tkinter.

Comment: I'd like to be able to click on the diagrams and manipulate them (move, edit its contents, etc.). I did search about graphviz and I know that it just creates png or other static representations of the diagrams.

Comment: Exactly, pysimpleautomata lets you make APIs too, which in-turn, you can use in tkinter to make GUI. Basically what I am saying is, we don't have an end to end tool, with API and visualization.